# Navigate among word headings with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to navigate between headings of the same type in word with keyboard? This would be equivalent to ctrl+arrow in emacs.

In outline or draft view. Can't find anything like it in help files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a macro and then assign a keyboard shortcut to it. Here is how the macro code looks (you can also create by recording it).

```
Sub Movebetweenheaders()
'
' Movebetweenheaders Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = Selection.Style
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub

Sub MovebetweenheadersBack()
'
' MovebetweenheadersBack Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = Selection.Style
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

If you're unsure how to assign a keyboard shortcut to a macro: [assign shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d)

EDIT from OP: I updated the code answer to the full solution to the question.

Comment: This looks really nice. First ever time to use macros, and it worked! Any idea how this coul be generalized to finding the headings of the same level? I did manage to make it move backwards by changing to Forward to False too.

Comment: I figured out what should be there, and updated the code to reflect the answer to the question. Many thanks, I couldn't have done it without you! :)

Comment: @puslet88 nice!